# How to use detection communities in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have a database has 5 columns

| f_id | s_id | date | title | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 506678 | 24-05-2005 | title | 0.987 |

I have made the connection to the network and make the network connected like this:

```
 path = 'data.csv'
 df = pd.read_csv(path) 

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='f_id, target='s_id', edge_attr=['weight','date'], create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

so now i want to detect communities to the direct graph any detection i know that louvian cannot be implemented to a direct network so not preference.

```
TypeError: Bad graph type, use only non directed graph
```

So how to detect communities  and give each community a color.

After defining the communities i want to pass the title and score to the nodes to test which community has the lowest score.

Any hint please

Answer (score 0):

I answered your other question about Louvain but have found this also in the meantime:

[graphology-communities-louvain](https://github.com/graphology/graphology-communities-louvain)

The author says that it will work on directed graphs. I have no worked with this at all but it may be an interesting place to start.